# AES-128-CBC issue with PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

I have a php code code like below

```
        $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
        $key = openssl_digest("OfVb3CjsZhnX81ZzjfAHuIiMtKEUyrt6", 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt("wsUser", $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        $result = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);
        //$result value will decode by http_build_query
        // $request_query["Key"] = $result;
        // $last_query = http_build_query($request_query);
```

I converted PHPcode to C# like this ;

```
            var cipher = "AES-128-CBC-----";
            var key = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OfVb3CjsZhnX81ZzjfAHuIiMtKEUyrt6"));            
            var ivlen = cipher.Length;
            byte[] iv = new byte[16]; Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.NextBytes(iv);
            var aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
            
            //C# 4.5 
            byte[] m = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(key, 0, m, 0, 16);
            aes.Key =  m;
            //C# 8.0
            aes.Key = key[0..16];
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key,iv);
            var ciphertextRaw = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtwsuser.Text), 0, txtwsuser.Text.Length); //this is "wsUser"
            var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(ciphertextRaw);
            string cw = Convert.ToBase64String(iv.Concat(hmac).Concat(ciphertextRaw).ToArray());
            textBox1.Text =  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cw).Replace("%3d", "%3D"); //this line for debug purposes
```

but even though the two hashes (key value and hmac value) are the same, PHP decryptor block doesn'T work.
my PHP decryptor code block like this;

```
        $encrypted_value = urldecode("data_from_client"); // can be used textBox1.Text value for this.
        $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
        $key = openssl_digest(wsKey, 'SHA256', TRUE);
        $cw = base64_decode($encrypted_value);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = substr($cw, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($cw, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
        $cw3 = substr($cw, $ivlen+$sha2len);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('SHA256', $cw3, $key, true);
        $result = openssl_decrypt($cw3, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

decrytor PHP code works with PHP code above, but C# doesn't work. I tried some AES methods but no change.How can AES-128 encryption be the same in php and C#. ?

Thanks in advance

C# code generated

```
sCn1%2bY2Kx9RzIiDIsWL1xWRxecMO%2bkPhIdkBfXbV6uD7%2by75f3EvwpyP4e3CHLDjBZ7U0CrVDsK4MdBUn25K0Q%3D%3D
```

value. PHP cannot decrypt the data. but hash values are correct.
PHP Code generated

```
%2FUMZJmd2LfIJzJntETKcgo%2F7VDaBV8U9iLY%2Bopq2Up5%2BrtOLRMxR%2B3OzbzgLEx0ZZErjZFP8oOtMmnZ%2FEX1dxA%3D%3D
```

this works fine.

After Add lines to C# Code at belows, problem solved

```
            //C# 4.5 
            byte[] m = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(key, 0, m, 0, 16);
            aes.Key =  m;
            //C# 8.0
            aes.Key = key[0..16];
```

Comment: I'll save you some work: you can throw away that code because the person that created that code forgot to include the IV in the calculation. What do you mean with "doesn't work" exactly? What do you expect us to do with ciphertext without keys?

Comment: I don't have any expectations. no one has to write an answer or comment.what is your problem?

Comment: There is a typo in your PHP decryption code: You must use `"OfVb3CjsZhnX81ZzjfAHuIiMtKEUyrt6"` as 1st parameter in the `openssl_digest()` call instead of `wsKey` as in the encryption code. Only then the decryption of the ciphertext generated with the PHP code `%2FUMZJmd...` is successful and returns `wsUser` as plaintext.

Comment: The cause of the problem is different AES variants in both codes. This is because SHA-256 is used for key derivation, which provides a 32-byte key. While in the PHP code the AES variant is *explicitly* specified and the too long key is shortened *implicitly*, in the C# code the AES variant is determined *implicitly* based on the keysize.

Comment: Therefore, decryption of the posted C# ciphertext is successful if `$cipher = "AES-256-CBC"` is used in the PHP decryption code. Alternatively, in the C# code `aes.Key = key[0..16]` can be used so that AES-128 is applied.

Comment: Thank you so much @Topaco, after you suggestion PHP decrypts the value with no error.  happy new year to you in advance.